# Crear un sistema de idiomas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Voy a crear una aplicación open-source para gestión con Kivy y quiero poder tener un menú para escoger entre los idiomas: Español, Gallego e Inglés y que el usuario pueda elegir el que desee.

Y luego otro archivo donde se guarde / cargue la configuración cada vez que se inicie la aplicación.

Se me ocurre crear un archivo settings.txt o similar con la línea

`lang = 0 | 1 | 2`
con el valor 0 (inglés) por defecto salvo que se cambie.

Comment: Te sugiero ir por el método "oficial" de internacionalización que tiene Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Patricio. Si puedes publícalo como respuesta a la pregunta para ayudar a otros usuarios.